# Eating meat on Hannuka?

Tags: halacha, minhag, food, chanuka, meat

Is there a source to require eating meat at the Hanuka meal?

Comment: CYLOR or CYLOM (Consult your local Orthodox Mekubal)!!!!

Comment: This isn't a practical Halachic question for me per se. I just want to know if there are any sources.

Comment: Is there a source for eating a meal on chanukah?

Comment: @avi I've seen sources for eating meals on Hanuka (I think Yalkut Yosef vol. 5 Siman Hilchot Hanuka

Comment: @avi, I seem to recall _Mishna B'rura_'s mentioning it.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill ( כ ) אוכל ושותה וכו' - ואפילו הוא מסגף עצמו מפני תשובה בכל ימות השנה שלא לאכול בשר ושלא לשתות יין בשבתות ויום טוב וחנוכה ופורים חייב לאכול ולשתות [בית יעקב סי' ע"ג ועיין במאירי מש"כ בענין זה בריש פ"ב דביצה]:

Comment: Minhag Tov #47 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8903&st=&pgnum=14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mishna Berura 529 note 19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=308) mentions in passing a requirement to eat meat and drink wine on Chanuka.

Comment: That's a good find!

Comment: Is this a positive requirement to eat meat and drink wine, or only that one may not fast from meat (intentionally go out of his way to abstain)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the source but there is a German custom to call the last night of Chanukah "Chanukas HaMizbeach and have a big yontif type of meal and serve meat and latkes. The traditional type of meat for this meal was duck or goose.